# How to edit javascript written inside html in firebug?

Tags: firebug

I know this question has been asked before and already has a answer. But none of the solution seems to be working for me.

I have a html file. Inside of it  I have written some javascript code. When I open the javascript inside scripts panel in Firebug, I am not able to edit the script . How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the objects accessible from the console? Are you trying to edit functions?

If they are global functions, you can edit them using:

```
window.functionName = function () { };
```

I usually edit global objects using the [Command Line](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line):

```
global.param = 1;
```

Comment: yes i am trying to edit a function. Basically inside a function there is one line which is commented. I want to uncomment it.

Comment: and where to add this statement ?? window.functionName = function () { };

Comment: in the "console" tab of firebug, there's an input box in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The Script panel currently (Firebug 1.12.7) doesn't allow to edit the JavaScript. See [issue 5083](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5083) in the Firebug issue tracker.

Though what you can do is to edit global functions within the [Command Editor](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Editor). It is available inside the [*Console* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel) by clicking on the arrow symbol ([image]) at the right side of the Command Line.

You can access and overwrite the global functions and variables within it.